# Beanstalkd / Pheanstalk - Cant get it working at all! (WAMP/PHP/LARAVEL)

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-4, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

So im trying to get Pheanstalk queue working in Laravel 4, which is built in (i had to composer instal the beanstalkd lib).

Now thats done... im trying to send jobs to my workers.
Everytime i do i get this error

```
[2013-04-25 08:55:03] log.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\adam\L4\vendor\pda\pheanstalk\classes\Pheanstalk\Socket\StreamFunctions.php line 55' in C:\wamp\www\adam\L4\vendor\pda\pheanstalk\classes\Pheanstalk\Socket\StreamFunctions.php:55
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\adam\L4\bootstrap\compiled.php(5006): Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleFatal()
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\ExceptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Exception\{closure}()
#2 {main} [] []
```

I also get this error in my log:

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job::resolveAndFire() must be of the type array, null given
```

Which seems to be looped as soon as i run 'php artisan queue:listen'.

I have downloaded the console for beanstalkd and configure it to listen to server localhost:11300.

Which gives me an error: unhandled response.

I have changed my httpd.conf and added Listen 11300 to it and restarted.

Any ideas where im going wrong? I cant see much docs for Beanstalkd and the Laravel docs dont help either.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2):

sorry `beanstalkd` is not available on Windows

Answer (score 0):

As an attempt to answer an old question legitimately for anyone reading, I propose the following.

As an alternative to using Pheanstalk, you could perhaps use Redis. There's a Chocolatey install for it:

https://chocolatey.org/packages/redis-64

You can install as a Windows service and access the command line tool after installation with:

```
    C:\> redis-cli
    C:\> 127.0.0.1:6379> <your command here>
```

You could perhaps use something like Forever to keep your queue command running in the background (with automatic restarts on fail if necessary):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

using a command like

```
    forever -c php artisan queue:listen -a -l C:\somelogdirectory\somelogfile.txt
```